# Use the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem to show $[0, 1]$ and $(0, 1)$ are equipotent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I have a solution, but I just want to make sure I'm doing it correctly:

Let $X$ be $[0, 1]$ and let $Y$ be $(0, 1)$, with functions $f: X → Y$ and $g: Y → X$.

Setting $f(x) = 1 / (x+2)$, we find that this is an injective function.

Setting $g(x) = x$, we find that this is also an injective function.

Because $f$ and $g$ are both injective, it follows that $X$ and $Y$ are equipotent?

Comment: Yup, that's right! Technically you should prove that $f$ and $g$ are indeed injective, and have appropriate ranges when restricted to $X$ and $Y$ respectively, but that's kind of silly. (Note that you can get slightly nicer - specifically, linear - injections from $X$ to $Y$.)

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm still getting used to all of the vocabulary, so I just wanted to make sure this was correct.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I thought your original idea to post this as answer was a good one :-)